# How to create a backup of .emacs every time Emacs starts

Tags: version-control, emacs, backup, configuration-files

What is a good way to take a backup of my .emacs file each time Emacs starts?  I want to keep multiple copies for when I need to get back to a previous version.

My first thought is to issue a shell command from within the .emacs file:

```
cp ~/.emacs ~/Backups/.emacs-yyyymmdd:hhmmss
```

... appending the current timestamp to get a unique filename.  But as far as I know you can't issue shell commands from the .emacs file.

I've read about [BackupEachSave](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupEachSave) and [ForceBackups](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups).  Does anyone have experience with these?  Do they work well?

EDIT:
Event_jr's answer about version control is a possible solution.  I prefer using a shell command, though, because version control applies to all files and I don't need multiple backups of every single file.

I looked at the 'version control' variable.  It's [described](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names) in the Emacs manual:

> Emacs can also make numbered backup files. Numbered backup file names contain ‘.~’, the >number, and another ‘~’ after the original file name. Thus, the backup files of eval.c >would 
>   be called eval.c.~1~, eval.c.~2~, and so on, all the way through names like eval.c.~259~ >and beyond.
>
> The variable version-control determines whether to make single backup files or multiple >numbered backup files.

So, I added this to my .emacs:

```lisp
; Version control and backups:
(setq version-control t)
```

Works as advertised.

[This section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) tells how to control backups on a per-file basis.  I haven't explored it.

Comment: You may want to consider keeping your .eamcs under version control. Lots of people do that.

Comment: "version control applies to all files"  Version control does not apply to all files, only to files which you explicitly put under version control. The version control software simply ignores those files which are not under its control.

Comment: Apparently there's a difference between "version control" and the variable called "version-control".  If the version-control variable is set, any file that's changed will be given numbered backups.

Comment: So you meant the variable, but it doesn't necessarily apply to all files either. You can set it as a buffer local variable only for those files for which you want to keep multiple backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as far as I know you can't issue shell commands from the .emacs file.

Sure you can:

```lisp
(shell-command "cp ~/.emacs ~/.emacs-`date +%Y%m%d:%H%M`")
```

Answer (score 8):

The question you should really be asking is how do I never lose a revision of any file I edit in Emacs, including `~/.emacs`?

The answer is [versioned backups](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory).  The variable that controls this feature is called `version-control`, which is kind of confusing, as it relates completely to backups, not VCS.

This is also a feature of Emacs; there is no additional package to install.  Almost everything I work on is in VCS, but I still find it extremely useful to have all revisions of my work easily accessible.  Storage is so cheap, so why not?

EDIT: describe the `save-buffer` aspect of backup every file.

You should read the documentation (<kbd>C-h k C-x C-s</kbd>) of `save-buffer` to understand the nuances, but basically passing it <kbd>C-u C-u</kbd> will force it to backup after every save.  I actaully remap it to my own function

```lisp
(defun le::save-buffer-force-backup (arg)
  "save buffer, always with a 2 \\[universal-argument]'s

see `save-buffer'

With ARG, don't force backup.
"
  (interactive "P")
  (if (consp arg)
      (save-buffer)
    (save-buffer 16)))
(global-set-key [remap save-buffer] 'le::save-buffer-force-backup)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use a version control system like `git`. It will be easier if you create an `~/.emacs.d` directory and put your elisp files in there:

```
mkdir ~/.emacs.d
mv .emacs ~/.emacs.d/init.el
git init
git add init.el
git commit -m 'initial checkin'
```

Now each time you modify the `init.el` file you can use the following to save the changes:

```
git commit -a -m 'descriptive commit message here'
```

You can then add a function to `after-save-hook`, such as something like this gist [to automatically add, commit, and push when files change](https://gist.github.com/1920281). After the push you then have a local copy and a remote copy (e.g. on github).

Emacs also has integration with git via a package called [magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/).

You'll be greatly rewarded in the long run if you spend the time now to learn how to use a [DVCS (Distributed Version Control System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) and you'll find that magit makes it very convenient to use `git`.

Comment: Hmmmmm.  I see the merits, but when I'm operating on such a small scale it sounds like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It always seems that way at first... you'd be surprised how quickly your scale will grow before you realize it. The time you spend now learning these tools on a small scale will pay great dividends later on when you have to tackle bigger projects. And even at a small scale you'll come to appreciate how helpful it can be. I type `git init` for every new project I start. And if you use [magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) it makes it simple to do the rest.

Comment: Upvoting because I agree, however git (which I also use) simply isn't the most user-friendly VCS around. It's extremely powerful and flexible, but in general I would be a little wary of pointing newcomers to VCS in its direction. (Magit *is* excellent and helps a lot, but it doesn't cover all the situations). By all means try git out (with Magit) and see if you like it, but do also be aware that there are simpler alternatives out there.

Comment: @phils I certainly agree that git is confusing... even if you're not a newcomer to VCS, however [github](http://github.com/) eases that pain somewhat in part because of its excellent documentation that helps people learn git, but mostly because it has a kick-ass web interface that beats the pants off rivals (launchpad, code.google.com, and (yuk) sourceforge are lacking in comparison). But if you're comparing purely on the command line, bazaar and mercurial are certainly much easier DVCS systems.

Answer (score 0):

You set backup properties as configuration; you can refer [here](http://snarfed.org/gnu_emacs_backup_files).